# How to correctly input a string and output?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm

```
  .data
sformat: .string "%s"
save:  .string "0"
alpha: .string "0"
      .text
      .globl st
st: stmfd sp!,{lr}
    ldr r0,=sformat
    ldr r1,=alpha
    bl scanf

    ldr r1,=alpha
    ldr r1,[r1]
    ldr r2,=save
    str r1,[r2]

    ldr r0,=sformat
    ldr r1,=save
    ldr r1,[r1]
    bl printf
    ldmfd sp!,{lr}
```

input:`A` output:`A`

I want to input a string and output it, now I have an error.

It shows `Segmentation fault`

I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Surely the last `ldr r1,[r1]` before `bl printf` is incorrect, since your format string contains `%s`. Also, doing word-sized loads and stores from/to `save` and `alpha` seems incorrect. I don't see what you even need `save` for in this program.

Comment: @Michael Thx. I delete some about ```save``` code, and it can work.